# Application "Disks" made filesystem readonly

Tags: filesystem, read-only

Running LXDE. Some partitions are not in fstab, so they were not mounted until I clicked onto them in the file manager. Since I wanted one of them to be automounted without editing fstab, I started Disks. I did not change anything, since automount was enabled there (although it obviously did not work). Since then, the partition is in readonly mode. Rebooting does not help.

The partition is still not listed in fstab, so what did Disks actually do and how can I revert it?

[image: The settings]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since there was no clear sign of what the problem was, I randomly started Windows and ran chkdsk on the partition. It had no errors. I rebooted, and now Lubuntu can write to the partition. It is obviously not sure, if chkdsk has anything to do with it.